# How do I print each iteration in Selection sort in C?

Tags: c, sorting, selection-sort

I am a newbie trying to learn C and I need to sort an array using selection sort. I also need to show each iteration as the algorithm progresses. But I cannot seem to make the following code work. It throws up random garbage numbers when executing the showing of the sorting iteration part (please see the picture). I have searched a lot and still can't seem to nail the cause of this error. Please help. [Program execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBSh5.png)

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{

int s,i,j,t,temp,a[20];
printf("Enter the number of elements in the array\n");
scanf("%d",&s);

for(i=0;i<s;i++)
    {
      printf("Enter element %d\n",i+1);
      scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }

printf ("Selection sort.\narray before sorting:\n");
for (i=0;i<s;i++)
    printf ("%d ",a[i]);

printf ("\n");

for(i=0;i<s;i++)
    {
      printf ("After iteration %d\n", i+1);
      for(j=i+1;j<s;j++)
        {
           if(a[i]>a[j])
               {
                 temp=a[i];
                 a[i]=a[j];
                 a[j]=temp;
               }
         }
      for (t=0;t<s;t++);
          printf ("%d ",a[t]);
      printf ("\n");
    }

printf("Array after sorting:\n");
for(i=0;i<s;i++)
    printf ("%d ",a[i]);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have a semicolon after the `for` loop inside the sorting loop. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: To avoid problems like that in the future, declare loop variables inside the loop: `for (int t=0;t<s;t++); printf ("%d ",a[t]);` wouldn't compile.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is this line:
`for (t=0;t<s;t++);`
Having that line end with `;` means that t will count up to s without any work being done and after that loop a single line will be printed with the uninitialized value of `a[s]`.

Comment: Ending a 'for statement' with a semi-colon. So embarassing. Thank you very much!! It worked now. As I said, newbie.